# Submit a form and data after c# code has performed a function

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms

I've read a lot of pages of questions and answers in regards form submitting in asp.net4.0 and the fact that it ignores the action="somepage.aspx" and posts back to itself only, but none have touched on what I have as an issue:

I have a form that posts details to a hosted payment page (i.e. not on my server) and this data is stored inside `<input type="hidden" ... >` controls, these controls get their data from my code behind, as this is just a confirmation page and the data is from a previous page. Up till now my form works fine, it posted the data through to the external hosted page on clicking the submit button. Great.

Now though I need to change the `<input type="submit" ... >` button to an `<asp:Button ... >` that runs a function in my code behind to log in a database that the button was clicked (it will store a click against a users ID) before posting the data to the hosted page.

Here is where my problem lies, I need two forms on my page, one with `runat="server"` for my overall page and it's asp.net controls, but another for my form and its `action="externalpage"`. But this gives the following error

> Control 'Submit' of type 'Button' must be placed inside a form tag
>   with runat=server.

which is impossible I'm beginning to believe as asp.net doesn't allow me too do what I want to do with my `action="somepage"`. I can't have both forms with `runat="server"`, I can't not have a second form and just put the

> method="post"  action="<%= m_szFormAction %>"

inside my overall form tag, as then it doesn't know what `<%= m_szFormAction %>` is.

Unfortunately, I'm really stuck and would appreciate any help / ideas how to submit form data to an external hosted page, after updating a database, using my c# code behind.

For clarity here is some example code, the 1st snippet worked ok originally, the second is what I need to do:

```
<body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
  <asp:Image ID="Image1"  runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/logo.jpg" />
 </form>
 <form method="post" action="<%= m_szFormAction %>">
    <input type="hidden" name="MerchantID" value="<%= m_szMerchantID %>" />
    <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Confirm Booking" />
 </form>
</body>
```

2nd snippet that throws errors

```
<body>
     <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <asp:Image ID="Image1"  runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/logo.jpg" />
     </form>
     <form method="post" action="<%= m_szFormAction %>">
        <input type="hidden" name="MerchantID" value="<%= m_szMerchantID %>" />
        <asp:Button ID="Submit" Text="Confirm" CssClass="btn" 
                OnClick="Submit_Click" runat="server"/>
     </form>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

One workaround would be to place a hidden `asp.net button` in a server form and virtually click it when the external button is pressed

```
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
  <asp:Image ID="Image1"  runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/logo.jpg" />
  <asp:Button ID="Submit_HomeServer" Text="Confirm" CssClass="btn" 
            OnClick="Submit_Click" runat="server" style="visible:false;display:none"/>
 </form>
 <form method="post" action="<%= m_szFormAction %>">
    <input type="hidden" name="MerchantID" value="<%= m_szMerchantID %>" />
    <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Confirm Booking" onClick="javascript:document.getElementById("Submit_HomeServer").Click()" />
 </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for your reply, I have decided to implement this on the transaction completed page using variables passed through the hosts server and back to mine. Which to be honest is the time to store what I needed to store. I will try out you suggestion though when I have time and reply here, as I never like to get beaten by a challenge to achieve something. Thanks.